# How to maintain layered absolute div alignment and sizing while scrolling and resizing?

Tags: html, css

I have a need to make wysiwyg editor as such:

1. A transparent textarea, with a transparent font is the editing component.
2. It is layered over a div which gets its value from the textarea and renders it.
3. editing interactions occur in the textarea but the view comes from the underlying div.

This way, we can render syntax highlighted text, while maintaining editing functionality of a textarea.

My problem is my lack of expertise in CSS. So no matter how many variations of this I try, there is always a problem with word wrapping, or scrolling, or alignments getting out of sync.

Supplied below is one variation. The editor component has transparent grey text while the underlying div is orange text, so we can see when they line up.

The challenge is to make them always line up, no matter what the content or scrolling or sizing.

```js
function update(){
  document.getElementById("richtext").innerHTML = 
  document.getElementById("editor").value;
}
```

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border : 1px solid grey;
}

.content {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre;
  display: block;
  overflow: none;
}

#richtext {
  z-index: -10;
  color: orange;
}

#view {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#editor {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #00000055;
  caret-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div id="view" class="content">
  <textarea id="editor" class="content" onInput="update();" class="content"></textarea>
  <div id="richtext" class="content"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you describe is unclear (from a technical point of view). Please create a *runnable* [mcve]. Also consider adding the results of your research to the question. Otherwise it will appear as if you conducted none.

Comment: I'll work on making this clearer. There is no SO requirement to show work done. And in fact, my work is being done in elm-ui, in elm. The solution to my problem starts by understanding the mechanics of a CSS solution, but my existing code won't help anyone here as this is not an elm/elm-ui specific issue. If you are curious, here is the code https://gist.github.com/z5h/493423f87f77bbdcf886159b21a3dc87#file-dumbdown-elm-L37

Comment: Regardless of the tools, backend technology or frontend framework used, this boils down to how browsers interpret your CSS output and you seem to need help with that. Don't provide the source code, provide a working example (based on the minimal amount of output (processed = what hits the browser) code necessary to reproduce it). Nobody said there is a SO requirement to show your research or existing code, but it would drastically increase your chances of getting a useful answer, which seems, in turn, to be your requirement/expectation.

Comment: @z5h Seems like you answered your own question. Put the 2 divs in a wrapper and give the wrapper a `height` and `overflow: auto`

Comment: Ok, I've added what I have. It doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to fix your problem is removing textarea and using `div` with `contenteditable="true"`. You might want to see how CKEditor do it.

Comment: @Duannx I'm using Elm, and there are many known issues with contenteditable. I'm avoiding it on purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Do you NEED the `textarea` and underlying div? I was trying to find a good rich text editor recently and noticed that many of the modern ones use, just a div with `contenteditable="true"` as an HTML5 attribute. Here are some [good examples](https://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2012/01/23/html5-contenteditable-and-css/) of this in the real world.

---

If you really need to stick with the two elements, I'd tear them both down to bare metal by resetting ALL attributes:

```
textarea,
.preview {
  all: initial;
}
```

Then build up the text styling so it's completely the same on both. `font-family`, `font-size`, `font-weight`, `line-height`, etc. I'd also make sure there's a good CSS reset or normalize in place.

The problem is that browsers treat text rendering differently in a textarea than elsewhere so the goal would be to force them to be the same by being a bit heavy-handed.

Comment: I'm using Elm, and there are many known issues with contenteditable. I'm avoiding it on purpose.

Comment: That's totally understandable. I gave you some a few CSS things to try as well. The problem is that browsers treat text rendering differently in a textarea than elsewhere so the goal would be to force them to be the same by by being a bit heavy handed

Answer (score 1):

Change class **.content** `min-height:100%;` to `min-height:100vh;` and also change `white-space: pre;` to `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Here is the updated fiddle:

```js
function update() {
  document.getElementById("richtext").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("editor").value;
}
```

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.content {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: block;
  overflow: none;
}

#richtext {
  z-index: -10;
  color: orange;
}

#view {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#editor {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #00000055;
  caret-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div id="view" class="content">
    <textarea id="editor" class="content" onInput="update();" class="content"></textarea>
    <div id="richtext" class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As the content gets longer it gets out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

The alignment gets out of sync because eventually you will exceed the defined height of the textarea and its internal scrolling kicks in.

To avoid this, update the textarea's height, so it extends automatically.

```
function update(){
  richtext.innerHTML = editor.value;

  editor.style.width = 'auto';
  editor.style.width = editor.scrollWidth+'px';

  editor.style.height = 'auto';
  editor.style.height = editor.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

```js
var richtext = document.getElementById("richtext")
var editor = document.getElementById("editor")

function update(){
  richtext.innerHTML = editor.value;
  
  editor.style.width = 'auto';
  editor.style.width = editor.scrollWidth+'px';
  
  editor.style.height = 'auto';
  editor.style.height = editor.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border : 1px solid grey;
}

.content {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre;
  display: block;
  overflow: none;
}

#richtext {
  z-index: -10;
  color: orange;
}

#view {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#editor {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #00000055;
  caret-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div id="view" class="content">
  <textarea id="editor" class="content" onInput="update();" class="content"></textarea>
  <div id="richtext" class="content"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: same goes for the width, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the absolute position. Thus div and textarea are placed on each other. remove position, min-width and max-width for div and textarea. and use display:flex-inline for div#view;
you can change value of white-space for better result.